# How pipe powershell commands in c#

Tags: c#, .net, powershell, exchange-server

The goal is get the smallest database of an Exchange 2010 site, so I'm trying to run the following powershell command from c#,

```
Get-MailboxDatabase -server Exchange2010 -Status | select-object Name,DatabaseSize
```

The problem I'm struggling is - how pipe the Select clause command.

This is my attemp,

```
WSManConnectionInfo wsConnectionInfo = new WSManConnectionInfo(new Uri("https://" + ExchangeSite + "/powershell?serializationLevel=Full"),
    "http://schemas.microsoft.com/powershell/Microsoft.Exchange", getCredential());
wsConnectionInfo.AuthenticationMechanism = AuthenticationMechanism.Basic;
wsConnectionInfo.SkipCACheck = true;
wsConnectionInfo.SkipCNCheck = true;

rsRemoteRunspace = RunspaceFactory.CreateRunspace(wsConnectionInfo);
rsRemoteRunspace.Open();
Pipeline pipeLine = rsRemoteRunspace.CreatePipeline();

Collection<PSObject> DatabaSize = null;

Command myCommand = new Command("Get-MailboxDatabase");
myCommand.Parameters.Add("Server", "Exchange2010");
myCommand.Parameters.Add("Status", null);
Command myCommand2 = new Command("Select-Object");
    myCommand.Parameters.Add("Name");
myCommand.Parameters.Add("DatabaseSize");
pipeLineMB.Commands.Add(myCommand);
pipeLineMB.Commands.Add(myCommand2);
DatabaSize = pipeLine.Invoke();
```

but I'm getting,

```
"A parameter cannot be found that matches parameter name 'Name'."
```

Please keep in mind I cannot use SnapIn because the code must run on a client machine that executes cmdlets on the Exchange server.

Any advice is welcome.

**EDIT**

I applied the fix suggested by yamen and the command was able to be invoked but when I try to get the value, I get: "Object reference not set to an instance of an object."

[image: exception]

Notice that I can get the values of Servername and Name but it fails in the DatabaseSize so I guess the 'Status' flag is not being set properly because this flag is the one which enables this value.

Comment: `select` is an alias for Select-Object, I don't think you can use aliases in the `Command` constructor (I generally do not.)

Comment: @MichaelEdenfield, if I change it to Select-Object then I get "A parameter cannot be found that matches parameter name 'DatabaseSize'". Notice the same command runs fine in powershell ISE, Get-MailboxDatabase -server exchange2010 -Status | select-object DatabaseSize

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here did you mean this:

```
Command myCommand2 = new Command("Select-Object");
myCommand2.Parameters.Add("DatabaseSize");
```

Instead of this:

```
Command myCommand2 = new Command("Select-Object");
myCommand.Parameters.Add("DatabaseSize");
```

Notice `myCommand2` on the second line?

Regardless, you might find that the parameter you're actually after is `Property` viz:

```
myCommand2.Parameters.Add("Property", "DatabaseSize");
```

And for more than one:

```
var props = new string[] { "DatabaseSize", "ServerName", "Name" };
myCommand2.Parameters.Add("Property", props);
```

Comment: I was able to invoked the command but now I get an error when try to get the value. I guess the -Status flag is not being applied properly, can you confirm please if I'm using it in the proper way. See my comments above.

Comment: Try either `myCommand.Parameters.Add("Status", true);` or just `myCommand.Parameters.Add("Status");` and report back.

Comment: I just realized that the flag must be entered in the followig way, myCommand.Parameters.Add("Status", true); Thank you.

Comment: yamen, unmarked the answer just to caught your attention, hopefully you get a notification and can comment on this thread. Thanks

Comment: @m0dest0 Can I suggest you open the new one as another question? It's going to be a different problem, and you're not really meant to use one question that you continually edit for different problems. People will be unlikely to answer your questions if they solve the problem and then you give another one and take the rep away.

Comment: Also note you can just type @yamen in a comment to page me. Do so in the new question and I'll take a look.

Answer (score 4):

I just tried this, to have a similar scenario

```
dir | select Name
```

It doesn't work. Gives me the same error saying 'Name' isn't a valid parameter. Then I tried the below, it works

```
dir | select -first 3
```

translates to

```
        Runspace runspace = RunspaceFactory.CreateRunspace();
        runspace.Open();
        Pipeline pipeline = runspace.CreatePipeline();
        Command dir = new Command("dir");
        pipeline.Commands.Add(dir);
        Command select = new Command("select");
        select.Parameters.Add("first", 3);
        pipeline.Commands.Add(select);
```

You would need to find the name of the parameter for which `DatabaseSize` is the value, I guess.

Comment: As per my answer, that parameter is called 'Property'.