# Creating a PowerShell pipeline to read async in C#

Tags: c#, powershell

I would like to create the equivalent in C# of this:

```
PS > Get-Disk | Get-Partition
```

I've tried with this:

```
using (var r = RunspaceFactory.CreateRunspace())
{             
    var pipeline = r.CreatePipeline();

    var gd = new Command("Get-Disk");
    var gv = new Command("Get-Partition");

    pipeline.Commands.Add(gp);
    pipeline.Commands.Add(gv);

    var results = pipeline.Invoke()
}
```

But **this is not sync**. I would like to create the pipeline and read from it asynchronously. Is it possible?

Thank you!

NOTE: This is related, but not async: [How pipe powershell commands in c#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10392901/how-pipe-powershell-commands-in-c-sharp)

Answer (score 2):

I was having some issues getting it to recognize the `Get-Disk|Get-Partition` command so I settled for `dir|select Name`. Hopefully in your environment you can substitute `Get-Disk|Get-Partition` back in.

This is using the `PowerShell` object from `System.Management.Automation`

```
using (PowerShell powershell = PowerShell.Create()) {
    powershell.AddScript("dir | select Name");

    IAsyncResult async = powershell.BeginInvoke();

    StringBuilder stringBuilder = new StringBuilder();
    foreach (PSObject result in powershell.EndInvoke(async)) {
        stringBuilder.AppendLine(result.ToString());
    }

    Console.WriteLine(stringBuilder);
}
```

For sake of example I am just calling `.BeginInvoke()` and the using `.EndInvoke(async)` to demonstrate the asynchronous part of this. You will need to adapt this to your needs (i.e. process the results differently, etc.) but I have used this `PowerShell` class many times in the past and found it very helpful.