# Can you recommend any NuGet packages for console app argument parsing and pipelining specifically for .NET 6.0?

Tags: c#, parsing, console, .net-6.0, pipelining

I'm currently looking for packages to help me develop a C# console app for automatisation in .NET 6.0, the packages should ideally support me in the following tasks:

- command line argument parsing
- autocompletion for parameters on the commandline (with TAB)
- "pipelining" or "chaining" the output from one command as input to the next, like it is done f.e. in powershell:

```
Command-1 | Command-2 | Command-3
```

Are there any packages that should be used for this specifically in .NET 6.0 (and the new command line template) ?

---

For "command line argument parsing" I implemented [CommandLineParser](https://www.nuget.org/packages/CommandLineParser) (last updated 5/1/2020) in the current prototype, which works fine, however [this article](https://blog.elmah.io/how-to-create-a-colored-cli-with-system-commandline-and-spectre/) recommends the new `System.CommandLine` and also mentions other packages, should I favour that in .NET 6.0 ? Regarding pipeling I found [this old SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10392901/how-pipe-powershell-commands-in-c-sharp), is pipelining even something that is done in C# console apps, or should I consider implementing PowerShell Cmdlets for that?

Comment: AutoCompletion of parameters on the command line is not a feature of your application. It is an feature of powershell and it is enabled through Attributes within your script ([some more explanation](https://powershell.one/powershell-internals/attributes/auto-completion)). If and how this can be used within a .Net application I don't know.

Comment: Thank you for the link, I will check it out. I was just looking at [this github repo](https://github.com/rohankapoor/AutoPrompt) for autocompletion for C# .NET console apps, but it hasn't been updated for ~2 years.